# "No default module defined" error in Zend Framework app

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping

I am in process of making my bootstrap.php file more organized, but after I put everything into separate static methods, I cannot load any page beyond index controller. E.g.
if I try to open

`http://localhost/zftutorial/login/index`

I get

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 
'Invalid controller class ("Login_IndexController")' in C:\Program 
Files\VertrigoServ\www\library\Zend\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:341 
Stack trace: #0 C:\Program 
Files\VertrigoServ\www\library\Zend\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(255): 
Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->loadClass('IndexController') #1 C:\Program 
Files\VertrigoServ\www\library\Zend\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(934): 
Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), 
Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #2 C:\Program 
Files\VertrigoServ\www\zftutorial\public\index.php(18): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() 
#3 C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\zftutorial\public\index.php(138): Bootstrap::run() #4
 {main} thrown in C:\Program 
Files\VertrigoServ\www\library\Zend\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php on 
line 341
```

and in my bootstrap file I seem to have defined where controllers chould be found:

```
public static function setupFrontController()
{
    self::$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    self::$frontController->throwExceptions(true);
    self::$frontController->returnResponse(true);
    self::$frontController->setBaseUrl('/zftutorial');

    self::$frontController->setControllerDirectory(
        array(
            'default' => self::$root . '../application/controllers',
            'admin' => self::$root . '../application/controllers',
            'index' => self::$root . '../application/controllers',
            'login' => self::$root . '../application/controllers',
            'user' => self::$root . '../application/controllers'
        )
    );

    self::$frontController->setParam('registry', self::$registry);

}
```

Perhaps it has to do something with routing, but my app worked fine with implicit routing before, e.g. other controllers worked well too. WHat is the source of above error? How can I test/find/fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your stack trace the error is *Invalid controller class ("Login_IndexController")*

This suggests that the class Login_IndexController doesn't exist.

You should have a file called IndexController.php in the login module's controller directory. The structure you have at the moment won't work because two modules can't have a controller with the same name. Change the structure to

```
self::$frontController->setControllerDirectory(
        array(
            'default' => self::$root . '../application/modules/default/controllers',
            'admin' => self::$root . '../application/modules/admin/controllers',
            'index' => self::$root . '../application/modules/index/controllers',
            'login' => self::$root . '../application/modules/login/controllers',
            'user' => self::$root . '../application/modules/user/controllers'
        )
    );
```

Create the IndexController.php in self::$root . '../application/modules/login/controllers and make sure the class is called Login_IndexController